# Box plot with multiple groups + Dots + Counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a boxplot with multiple groups in R.

When i add the dots within the boxplots, they are not in the center. 
Since each week has a different number of boxplots, the dots are not centered within the box.

The problem is in the geom_point part.
I uploaded my data of df.m in a text file  and a figure of what i get.

I am using ggplot, and here is my code:

```
setwd("/home/usuario")
dput("df.m")
df.m = read.table("df.m.txt")
df.m$variable <- as.factor(df.m$variable)
give.n = function(elita){
return(c(y = median(elita)*-0.1, label = length(elita))) 
    }
p = ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value))
p = p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Label))    
p = p + geom_point(aes(fill = Label), shape = 21, 
         position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0))
p = p + stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median)
p
```

Here is my data in a text file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kpMx7Ao01bAol5eUC6BZUiulLBKV_rtH/view?usp=sharing

Only in variable 12 is in the center, because there are 3 groups (the maximum of possibilities!

I would also like to show the counting of observations. If I use the code shown, I can only get the number of observations for all the groups. I would like to add the counting for EACH GROUP.

Thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc35W.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, note: Only in week 12 is in the center, because there are 3 groups (the maximum of possibilities!

Comment: Hi Elia, welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you provided some sample data that would produce a graph similar to what you're getting on other people's systems. The reason is it's hard to troubleshoot problems without a working set of code+data. Also, if you have additional information to add, edit your question rather than adding a comment under it.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df.m)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df.m, 20))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer with OP's dataset:

Using some generated data and `geom_point()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df.m <- df.m %>%
  mutate(variable = as.factor(variable)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))

ggplot(df.m, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Label)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete("variable", drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much in davance. I updated my post now. I uploaded my data using your code for geom_point, however i dont get it centered when in variable 1 for instance there is only 1 group. They are only in the center for variable 12 where are 3 groups (maximum of possibilities)

Comment: Did you included: `df.m$variable <- as.factor(df.m$variable)` ?

Comment: Yes sorry, in the transcription of my code to here i have forgotten to include that. Now is included in my updated post. So with the code i use in my post i get the picture uploaded

Comment: @EliaPōpoki The answer is updated using your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `boxplot` and `dotplot` and an example dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
dt <- data.frame(week = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                  value  = c(6.40,6.75,6.11,6.33,5.50,5.40,5.83,4.57,5.80,
                             6.00,6.11,6.40,7.00,3,5.44,6.00,5,6.00),
                  donor_type = c("A","A","A","A","CB","CB","CB","CB","CB",
                                 "CB","CB","CB","CB","CB","A","A","A","A"))

# create the plot
ggplot(dt, aes(x = factor(week), y = value, fill = donor_type)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position = position_dodge(0.75))
```

[image]

You should be able to adjust my code to your real dataset easily.

Comment: THank you very much, however i dont get it in my example of data frame, i dont understand why, maybe it is because of my NA?

Comment: I think the easiest way for us to help you is to post your data somewhere in your question, so we can replicate the issue and fix it. You can use `dput` as suggested in the comments above.